# JQuery Datatable - How to show processing before it is rendered?

Tags: jquery, html, datatable

I am using jquery datatable plugin. It works fine. But the problem is, I have few large no. of table rows from server. So before datatable renders it, all the rows are shown as plain list, which is not looking good. It takes some time to render, then it works fine. So, how to show some kind of loading image instead of list of rows, before datatable renders completely.

HTML contains a normal table whose rows are generated by using for loop.

Jquery code is as follows, written in document.ready() method.

```
$("document").ready(function()
{
     $('#inbox_table').dataTable({
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers"
    });
});
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$('#inbox_table').dataTable({
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "oLanguage": {
        "sProcessing": "<img src='loading.gif'>"
    }
});
```

Reference

```
http://datatables.net/usage/i18n#oLanguage.sProcessing
```

Answer (score 0):

var table = $('#mytable').DataTable({

language : {

sLoadingRecords : 'http://www.snacklocal.com/images/ajaxload.gif'

}

})